# Two Limit Clauses in one statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to build a product review page where users can comment any submitted reviews like Amazon. I want the page to display **3** user reviews as well as **2** responses to each of the reviews if they exist.

Here's the [table](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18dbcb/4)

```
CREATE TABLE product_review
    (`ID` int, `username` varchar(21), `review_title` varchar(30), `review_or_reply` int)
;

INSERT INTO product_review
    (`ID`, `username`, `review_title`, `review_or_reply`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Tom', 'Rip-off', 0),
    (2, 'Peter', 'Rip-off', 1),
    (3, 'May', 'Rip-off', 1),
    (4, 'June', 'Rip-off', 1),
    (5, 'Tommy', 'Worth the Price', 0),
    (6, 'Sammy', 'Worth the Price', 1),
    (7, 'Sam', 'Worth the Price',1),
    (8, 'Bryan','Worth the Price',1),
    (9, 'Sally', 'Average Product', 0)
;
```

The review_or_reply field is effectively a Yes or No field, where `0` means it's a review and `1` is the review's comments by other users.

Is there a single select statement that can limit 3 reviews and bring up two of their comments? For example:

```
Select `username`,`review_title`,`reply` from product_review where review_or_reply ='0' Limit 3
Select `username`,`review_title`,`reply` from product_review where review_or_reply = '1' and title = 'Rip-off' Limit 2
Select `username`,`review_title`,`reply` from product_review where review_or_reply = '1' and title = 'Worth the Price'  Limit 2
Select `username`,`review_title`,`reply` from product_review where review_or_reply = '1' and title = 'Average Product'  Limit 2
```

I want the output to be like this:

```
username   review_title     review_or_reply
Tom          Rip-off         0
Peter        Rip-off         1
May          Rip-off         1
Tommy        Worth the Price 0
Sammy        Worth the Price 1
Sam          Worth the Price 1
Sally        Average Product 0
```

Comment: Gather with `UNION ALL`

Comment: what do you want the result to look like?

Comment: @JohnRuddell I've updated the post, please check it again.

Comment: You're looking for the first 2 comments from the first 3 reviews?

Comment: @Andreas, Yes, Each review has its own comments. I want each review to show 2 of their own comments if comments exist

Comment: So everyone's reviewing the same thing!?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will return 3 review_titles and then pull out two responses to that

```
SELECT 
    pr.*, 
    IF( @A = t.review_title, 
        IF(@B = 3, @B := 1, @B := @B +1)
        , @B
    ) AS group_col, 
    @A := t.review_title 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        username,
        review_title 
    FROM product_review 
    WHERE reply ='0' LIMIT 3
) t
JOIN product_review pr ON pr.review_title=t.review_title
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @A := "", @B := 1) AS temp
GROUP BY group_col, review_title
ORDER BY id;
```

---

**EDIT:**

if there are **more than one reply** that is 0 in the database like so then this query will check for that. (since you did specify in the other queries that the reply had to be 1).

```
INSERT INTO product_review
    (`ID`, `username`, `review_title`, `reply`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Tom', 'Rip-off', 0),
    (2, 'Peter', 'Rip-off', 1),
    (3, 'May', 'Rip-off', 0),
    (4, 'June', 'Rip-off', 1),
    (5, 'Tommy', 'Worth the Price', 0),
    (6, 'Sammy', 'Worth the Price', 1),
    (7, 'Sam', 'Worth the Price',1),
    (8, 'Bryan','Worth the Price',1),
    (9, 'Sally', 'Average Product', 0),
    (10, 'Timothy', 'Rip-off', 1)
```

**notice** that at id 3 there is a reply of 0 with id 10 a reply of 1. this query will correctly skip the reply = 0.

```
SELECT 
    pr.*, 
    IF( @A = t.review_title, 
        IF(pr.reply = 0, 1, 
            IF(@B = 3, @B := 1, @B := @B +1)
        ), @B
    ) AS group_col, 
    @A := t.review_title 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT
        id, 
        username,
        review_title 
    FROM product_review 
    WHERE reply ='0' 
    GROUP BY review_title
    LIMIT 3
) t
JOIN product_review pr ON pr.review_title=t.review_title
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @A := "", @B := 1) AS temp
GROUP BY group_col, review_title
ORDER BY id;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18dbcb/20)

Comment: @RedGiant i just updated the query. please use the updated query. it will not error when there is a reply that is 0... basically if there are two reply's with 0 then this will solve that too.

Answer (score 0):

...or slower but simpler...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM product_review x 
  JOIN product_review y 
    ON y.review_title = x.review_title 
   AND y.id <= x.id 
 GROUP  
    BY x.id 
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3 
 ORDER 
    BY MIN(y.id) 
 LIMIT 3;
```