# ORDER by rating ASC not working in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Please take a look at this **[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35c36/11)**

I'm working on a product review page where several approved reviews will be shown as well as approved responses to each of them. In the `TYPE` field, `0` means it's a review where `1` means it's a reply to one of the reviews. The repliers aren't allowed to rate the product, so it's NULL in the `rating` field. `ID_GROUP` represents which reviews the replies belongs to.

I got the following statement from user John Ruddell in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936690/two-limit-clauses-in-one-statement)

```
SELECT pr.*, 
IF( @A = t.id_group, 
   IF(pr.type = 0, 1, 
      IF(@B = 5, @B := 1, @B := @B +1) ), @B ) 
AS group_col, @A := t.id_group 
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT id, id_group 
      FROM `product_review` 
      WHERE type ='0' 
      AND approved <> '0' 
      GROUP BY id_group 
      ORDER BY rating ASC // <-- This doesn't work
      LIMIT 0, 5 ) t 
JOIN `product_review` pr 
ON pr.id_group=t.id_group 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @A := '', @B := 1) AS temp 
WHERE approved <> '0'
GROUP BY group_col, id_group 
ORDER BY id_group,time ASC
```

It's working fine. However I can't yield the following result by adding an additional `ORDER BY rating ASC` at line 11:

```
ID  USERNAME    ID_GROUP    TYPE    RATING  APPROVED    TIME    GROUP_COL
5   Tommy          5         0        2        1    1406937041     2    
9   Sally          5         1      (null)     1    1407871782     3    
3   May            3         0        3        1    1406237410     2    
7   Sam            3         1      (null)     1    1406999453     3    
1   Tom            1         0        5        1    1406232341     1    
2   Peter          1         1      (null)     1    1406237052     2
```

Can anyone show me how to get this output?

Comment: is it because you are ordering in the subquery ? I would suggest you need to select `rating` in the subquery then add `t.rating` to your `order by`

Comment: @Hugh Jones, my original fiddle isn't able to sort reviews that don't have replies. Your suggestion has fixed that. [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/487223/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `DESC` specifier when ordering by `id_group`, like so:

```
ORDER BY id_group DESC, time ASC
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35c36/14)